# Magento 2 Build Xml Request For External API

Tags: magento2, xml, http-request

I would need to pass request payload in XML format for a web service. Below is the code I tried.

**How do I verify & view XML is constructed properly?**

Is there a better **Magento** way to create an XML request since a big payload needs to be constructed?

***Note***: object manager being is used for testing purposes

```
$xmlFactory=$obj->get('\Magento\Framework\Simplexml\ElementFactory');
    $xmlHeader = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OrderStatusQuery xmlns="http://some-schema"></OrderStatusQuery>';

    $request=$xmlFactory->create(['data'=>$xmlHeader]);
    $request->addChild("OrderNumbers","","");
    $request->addChild("OrderNumber","1234567");

    $http->setUri('https://some-external-api-endpoint');
    $http->setHeaders(['Content-Type: text/xml']);
    $http->setMethod(\Zend_Http_Client::POST);
    $http->setRawData($request);
    $responseBody = $http->request()->getBody();
    var_dump($responseBody);
```